# Showing a BottomSheetScaffold with a BottomNavigation - Compose UI - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-ui

Using Compose UI, I have a bottom navigation bar and a Bottom Sheet,

so starting a "BottomSheetScaffold" from "Catalogue" screen is causing the "Bottom Nav Bar" to stay visible.

**How can I show "BottomSheetScaffold" making it cover the whole Screen (covering the bottom nav. bar),**
but keeping in mind to write the "BottomSheetScaffold" in the Compose Screen [Catalogue] itself, NOT on a higher level (Parent Activity Level) since it doesn't seem right

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

If I didn't misunderstood the question, you can wrap your content with a `ModalBottomSheetLayout`.

```kotlin
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
    sheetContent = {
        BottomSheetContent()
    }
) {
    Scaffold(...)
}
```

The result would be something like this:

[image]

It's not totally related to your question, but if you want to avoid the *half-expanded* state, you can do the following:

1. Declare the function below:

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
suspend fun ModalBottomSheetState.forceExpand() {
    try {
        animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
    } catch (e: CancellationException) {
        currentCoroutineContext().ensureActive()
        forceExpand()
    }
}
```

2. In your Bottom Sheet declaration, do the foollowing:

```
val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
    confirmStateChange = {
        it != ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded
    }
)
```

3. Call the following to show/hide the Bottom Sheet:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
    if (modalBottomSheetState.isVisible) {
        modalBottomSheetState.hide()
    } else {
        modalBottomSheetState.forceExpand()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that if we want to hide tab bar on opening  bottom sheet, we need to wrap bottom tab bar with bottom sheet? We lose a lot of with this :(

Comment: works like a spell :)

Comment: it doesn't help. In my case I have a scaffold which has a content and bottom navigation. On click of each menu in bottom sheet navigation I change the content of upper portion. I need to show the bottomSheet in one of those content/screens and I want to hide bottom navigation when showing the bottom sheet. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution that I use is passing lambda function that will change bottom bar visibility to compose screen